# Checking for null is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this very simple code to check whether the value is null or not but, it is not working and passing through the 'if' condition.

[image]

Code:

```
var existingFilterCriteria = filterCriteriaSectionRow.data('filterapplied');

if (existingFilterCriteria != null && existingFilterCriteria != '' && existingFilterCriteria != 'null');
{
    MappingQueryFilter = existingFilterCriteria;
}
```

**Question:**

Am I doing anything wrong here? Is there any special check I have to do for data returned from the 'data' attribute in a DOM element?

Comment: What is the value of `filterCriteriaSectionRow.data('filterapplied')`? What is the expected output? How do you define "working"?

Comment: Also, the code you showed in the screenshot of the code is different than the code you copied and pasted. For example, `!=` and `!==` are by no means the same thing.

Comment: Use or operator than and operator.

Comment: @JoshBeam, I agree. I was trying different options to capture the null check. Let me update the code.

Comment: try this way: `if(existingFilterCriteria) { .. `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a `;` at the end of your if statement.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem but still it should be or operator than and operator.

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal why? what if the value is '''. He would still go inside when he doesn't want to

Comment: NO, both case wouldn't match anytime as null !== ''

Comment: @brso05, you care correct. The semicolon (;) was causing the issue. After I removed it, things started to work fine. I don't know how I missed it. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal he only wants to execute the block of code if `existingFilterCriteria` contains something a non null non empty string...